# How to select a random number with weight in MySQL

Tags: mysql, random

I want to choose a random number between 1 and 12, but with weights, i.e. 4, 5, 6 should have 50% of the chance and 1,2,3,7,8,9,10,11,12 will have the other 50% of the chance. I did with the following code but is there a more efficient way of doing this instead of repeating the same number twice to achieve the weighting?

```
select v_month from
(select 4 as v_month
union select 4
union select 5
union select 5
union select 6
union select 6
union select 1
union select 2
union select 3
union select 7
union select 8
union select 9
union select 10
union select 11
union select 12
) as tbl4
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is wrong. You'd need to use UNION ALL for this.

Comment: if it is weighted then it wouldn't be random..

Comment: why not use php, I mean why do you want to do it in mysql?

Comment: @ Strawberry - thanks, I should have used union all.

Comment: @ CodeBird - I don't know php at all, that is why I am doing this in MySQL.

Comment: @ ylun - I don't necessarily agree. I think you can still generate randomness with a weight. I have seen this technique been used in other cases. Maybe we have a diff. understanding of the 'randomness'.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it like this if you are going to use query

1- create try table and put there values

```
CREATE TABLE try
(`id` int)
;

INSERT INTO try
(`id`)
VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(4),
(5),
(5),
(6),
(6),
(7),
(8),
(9),
(10),
(11),
(12)
 ;
```

then easily run this query

```
  select id from try
  order by rand()
  limit 1;
```

- For optimisation this will be much faster then yours.

i tested it your query takes 6ms and this query takes 1ms